# How to extract mysql slow query log of particular date from large file?

Tags: mysql, linux, shell, mysql-slow-query-log

I have a large slow query log file. 
i want to check the queries of a particular date in last week.
Its very tough to scan the file and go the particular date.

Is there any command to extract the slow log queries of a particular date from that large file ?

Any linux command or something..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`pt-query-digest` has `--since` and `--until`.  [Reference](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-query-digest.html).

And the default output will display the 'worst' queries first.

(See Comments for further tips.)

Comment: You can also dump the output of the excerpt in raw slow-log format instead of the usual digest report by using the `--output slowlog` option.

Comment: Minor enhancement to Bill's comment, using `--output slowlog --no-report` displays _only_ the slow log.